# How to create a link to send the woocommerce order to my whatsapp on my thank you page? I'm trying something like this code, but it's not working

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to include the full order link in a message to my whatsapp. After completing the purchase, the customer will click this link to send his order to my whatsapp.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_link' );
function send_order_link( $order ) {
$link .= '<p><a href="https://wa.me/5513123456789?text=This is my order:'.$order->get_checkout_order_received_url.'">Send order</a></p>'; 
echo $link;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off investigating the WhatsApp API to automate this instead of hoping the user correctly clicks the link and sends you a message.

Comment: 1) You forgot to _call_ the `get_checkout_order_received_url` function. 2) You forgot to encode the URL. 3) What ceejayoz said - because what if the customer doesn't even have WhatsApp, or they don't have it on the desktop, or they simply don't see and therefore don't click the link?

Comment: @CherryDT Thanks for the answer. Almost 90% of visits to my website come from cell phones and all my clients contact me via whatsapp. The link to order in whatsapp makes it easy.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm studying about how this API works too. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I did! I created a template to override the original woocommerce template order-details.php
I inserted this line of code in the template:

```
 <?php $link_whats = "https://wa.me/5513996004985?text=".$order->get_checkout_order_received_url()."MyEncodedText"; echo "<a href='$link_whats' target='_blank'><button>WhatsApp</button></a>" ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to call function is not object.  call as function

Instead of:❌

```
   $order->get_checkout_order_received_url
```

Use this:✅

```
   $order->get_checkout_order_received_url()
```

.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_link' );
    function send_order_link( $order ) {
    $link .= '<p><a href="https://wa.me/5513123456789?text=This is my order:'.$order->get_checkout_order_received_url.'">Send order</a></p>'; 
    echo $link;
    }
```

Ref https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Order::get_checkout_order_received_url

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this way only works if I remove the whatsapp link. When I put the whatsapp link again the link to the order disappears.  This way, without the parentheses: add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_link' );  function send_order_link( $order ) { $link .= '<p><a href="'.$order->get_checkout_order_received_url.'">Send order</a></p>';  echo $link; }